# Plotting curves with color gradient in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Might be a basic `ggplot2` question, but I'm struggling a bit.

For example, I have a vector as follows:

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

As the numbers are decreasing from left to right, and then increasing from the middle, I want make a simple line curve(like the basic `plot()` function) for this vector. So for this, I would get something like an inverse bell.

But how do I set the line to be coloured, based on the value of the number?

The higher the number, the more the **red** the curve, and the more **white** for vice-versa, just like in a heatmap.

So for this specific vector I would want to plot an inverse bell, with the sides of the curves in colour red, the middle in colour white and the intermediates in gray.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the colour aesthetic to `y`. Below is an example using your color specification. I've used the default gray background so that the white portion of the line will be visible, though it would probably work better to use a higher-contrast color for the gradient:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat = data.frame(x=1:19, y=c(10:1,2:10))

ggplot(dat, aes(x,y, colour=y)) +
  geom_line(size=1) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="white", high="red")
```

[image]

In the above example, the colour will be the same between each x value and will be set based on the x value at the left end of each segment. If you want the colour gradient to be interpolated between x values for smoother color transitions, you can plot an interpolated data frame:

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(approx(dat$x, dat$y, xout=seq(1,19,length=1000))), 
       aes(x,y, colour=y)) +
  geom_line(size=1) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="white", high="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Define colors using the sapply.     This example uses the predefined heat map.

```
values <- c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
heatcols <- heat.colors(10)
plot(values, xlab = '', ylab = '', 
    col = sapply(values, function(x) (heatcols[x])))
```

[image: plot produced]

The color map can be anything you choose.  Just use your choice of RGB values.

```
> heatcols
 [1] "#FF0000FF" "#FF2400FF" "#FF4900FF" "#FF6D00FF" "#FF9200FF" "#FFB600FF" "#FFDB00FF" "#FFFF00FF"
 [9] "#FFFF40FF" "#FFFFBFFF"
```